# Динамический список в формах бизнес-процессов Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Мне нужно решить достаточно тривиальную задачу, но штатными методами бизнеc-процессов Битрикс сделать это не получилось, а т.к. я не знаю php, то задача оказалась для меня нерешаемой.

Суть задачи: Есть некий каталог техники, реализованный с помощью списка (атрибуты id инфоблока - 73, поля списка: MODEL, SOTRUDNIK) . Необходимо создать бизнес-процесс для приемки новых сотрудников. В ходе выполнения процесса одна из задач должна быть поставлена сотрудникам с id 122 и 123. В форме задачи должен быть выпадающий список, в котором должны отображаться только те элементы списка "Каталог техники", у которых атрибут "SOTRUDNIK" = Null.

Насколько я понимаю, наиболее "правильным" решением было бы включить в бизнес-процесс приемки нового сотрудника компоненту произвольного php-кода. И использовать метод "SelectBoxFromArray" (https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/functions/html/selectboxfromarray.php). Но все мои попытки добиться отображения dropdown и самой формы ни к чему не привели.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно корректно написать php-код или, возможно, есть какой-то более простой вариант?